# python reading 8 byte block bin file

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I'm not familiar with reading binary file in python

I want to read bin file each 8 byte of block which it content would be

- byte 1: integer of 0-255
- byte 2: integer of 0-255
- byte 3-4: date string with format of dd.mm.yyyy
- byte 5-6: time string with format of hh:mm:ss
- byte 7: integer of 0-255
- byte 8: crc

I tried following
`

```
with open("tes.bin", "rb") as f:
        byte = f.read(8) 
        while byte != "":
            byte = f.read(8)
```

`
I'm not sure how I can treat byte var to extract the correct data

After reading the doc again, it is said that date is in bytes 3 and 4.

So it said bits 0-4 represent day of 2^5, bits 5-8 representing month of 2^4 and bits 9-15 represent the year of 2^7.

How can I do operation on python from bytes to bit in python

Could please anyone point me some hint?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I'm using python 2.x
not sure what is the correct struct.unpack param that I can use for fmt, any hint please?

Comment: You'd probably better find better documentation about the format of your file; 2 bytes isn't really enough to encode a _string_ with format dd.mm.yyyy - normally that would be at least 10 bytes.  This suggests that your date field (and time field) is a number of some sort.

Comment: You may find that using a binary file editor on your file will help you ferret out what it contains, in what format.  I'm partial to http://sourceforge.net/projects/bpe/ - but there are many of them.

Comment: After reading the doc again, it is said that date is in bytes 3 and 4. So it said bits 0-4 represent day of 2^5, bits 5-8 representing month of 2^4 and bits 9-15 represent the year of 2^7.
How can I do operation on python from bytes to bit

Comment: Getting flashbacks to the nasty [FAT timestamp format](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/FAT#FAT_date_and_time_values), which supports only even seconds to fit in 16 bits.